# return all values as one with a list of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

Note:I've been looking online, and even though i couldn't find the answer I was looking for I'm pretty sure its out there so please forward me to it if this has been answered. Sorry for the double post if there is one.

Hi, I'm trying to get the the values of one key inside a list of arrays. My Goal is to get the sum of a "column"

For example:

Heres my list of arrays

```
var total = 0;

var dataset= [
    {"cost" : 5.00 , "name" : "Victor" },
    {"cost" : 6.00 , "name" : "Jack" },
    {"cost" : 7.00 , "name" : "Bill" },
    {"cost" : 8.00 , "name" : "Delilah" },
    {"cost" : 9.00 , "name" : "Robert" },
    {"cost" : 10.00 , "name" : "Marisa" }
]
```

Is there any way to get the sum of all cost fields in one go. Or is there a way to get the cost values displayed as one array in one go?

if i get the all the values for the cost field i would want it to look like this:

```
[5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00]
```

If theres a built in function that im unaware about then i would get this:

```
total = dataset["cost"].sum(); <-- pseudo code

console.log(total) //would print 45
```

**i want to avoid looping through each index of my dataset.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, JavaScript is not R.

Comment: `.reduce` is what you're after, but it does loop. You can't avoid looping in this case unless you keep track of the cost externally as you add to/remove from the dataset. `let total = dataset.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next, 0)`

Comment: you can use [_reduce_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

Comment: @SergeyA What do you mean? JavaScript is a general purpose lanaguage.

Comment: @stanpines, while R is not :) In R, you would be able to do this with a single line without any nested functions.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate! You can use the handy procedures that JavaScript gives us!

To retrieve the sums of all the `costs`, you can do this...

```
function sums( array ) {
    return array.reduce(function(last, current) { return last + current['cost'] });
}
```

pass in `dataset` to get the sum.

Comment: map here just duplicate loop

Comment: I tried doing that but it didnt return one number. It returned each cost. Is there a way to reduce all the cost values into one array?

Comment: @JoshuaJLIVEWilliams to get the costs into one array, `dataset.map(function(obj) { return obj['cost'] })`. My function adds them together, but the thing I just posted will give you the array of costs.

Comment: Thanks guys i had to first use `dataset.map(function(obj) { return obj['cost'] })`

and then use the newly mapped array with the reduce function. After that it worked like a charm. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

anyway you need to iterate through array. You can do it via array.reduce

```
var result = dataset.reduce(function(sum, current) {
  return sum + current.cost;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum all values from an Array with Array.prototype.reduce:

```js
var total=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
console.log(total)
```

Comment: in order to use your method i would need my cost array to be reduced into one array. However my cost values are split across multiple arrays, is there anyway to reduce it to one?

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) makes this easy:

```
return _.sum(_.pluck(dataset, 'cost'))
```

Comment: I don't see the need for a big library just to use one function.

Comment: Lodash eventually gets used everywhere in a codebase once you pay the penalty of getting it available. In a browser, 450 bytes is almost negligible. In a node application, the cost is essentially free (I am almost certain at least one of your project's dependencies use it). It's cleaned up countless four and five line functions into one liners (no need to roll your own `util.js` anymore!).